# Consume Opentext Rest API using Groovy

Tags: rest, groovy, opentext

I need to create a group in opentext using their Rest API using Groovy:
[image]

So I tried to use this code

```
    @Grab(group='org.apache.httpcomponents', module='httpclient', version='4.5.2')

import groovy.json.*
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*
import org.apache.http.entity.*
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*

// build JSON
def map = [:]
map["type"] = 1
map["name"] = "ThisIsAGroup"
def jsonBody = new JsonBuilder(map).toString()

// build HTTP POST
String auth = "login:Password";
String encoding = auth.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
def url = 'https://link_of_my_server/api/v2/members'
def post = new HttpPost(url)
post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
post.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonBody))

// execute 
def client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def response = client.execute(post)
def bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()))
def jsonResponse = bufferedReader.getText()
```

unfortunately, it shows me this error message : [image]

with Response Code = 400

PS: When I try to consume a "Get/ PUT/ DELETE" method , this piece of code works like magic ! the problem appears only with the "POST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is : in order to use the creation option you need to use `MultipartEntityBuilder` and here it is the code that worked for me :

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpResponse response = null;

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://path_to_my_server/otcs/cs/api/v1/members");
        String auth = "login:password";
        String encoding = auth.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
        request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.addPart("type",  new StringBody("1",ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
        builder.addPart("name",  new StringBody("groupName",ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        request.setEntity(entity);
        response = client.execute(request);
```